# Download JS File from google drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, web-frontend

I am using the google picker API to select documents from a user's google drive. What I want to do is after the user selects a generic file type (non-docs, non-sheets, non-slides etc), I want to download the file and get a JS File object, and be able to use it as if it were coming from a browser file input. I want to do all of this in the frontend only, without sending the content to any server.

Here is what I have till now:

```
downloadFile(fileId) {
  return this._getGoogleFileInfo({fileId, alt: 'media'});
}

_getGoogleFileInfo(options) {
  return this._wrapGPromise(
    this._window.gapi.client.drive.files.get(options));
}
```

The `downloadFile` method returns some content, and I am not sure if that is binary, or base64, or a blob. I have tried converting it to base64, Blob, and File and use it as a File object, but none of them seem to work correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples

Comment: Hey @GuyYogev, thanks for your comment. Yes, I have looked at those docs, and that is exactly what I am using. However, I get the file contents as a text/plain, utf-8 string, and I am struggling trying to figure out how to generate a JavaScript File object from that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For example, when I select a PDF from the picker, I get something like: %PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 4 0 R
/Outlines 2 0 R
/PageMode /UseNone
/ViewerPreferences <<
/HideToolbar false
/HideMenubar false
/HideWindowUI false
/FitWindow false
/CenterWindow false
/DisplayDocTitle false
>>
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Outlines
/Count 0
>>
endobj
3 0 obj

[/PDF /Text /ImageC]
endobj
4 0 obj
<<

Comment: When I select a plain-text file, I get the plain-text contents of that file, and so on.